# How do I evaluate this integral using Beta functions?

Tags: definite-integrals, beta-function

How do I evaluate this integral using Beta functions?

$$\int_a^\infty e^{2ax-x}dx$$

Edit 1:The answer given for this question is :
$$e^{a^2}* \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$$

How do I get that using Beta functions?
I have been breaking my head over it for a long time.

Edit 2: There's a possibility that the answer given is wrong. Even then is it possible to solve it using Beta functions?

Comment: Please can you check the integrand? Is it $e^{2ax-x}=e^{(2a-1)x}$?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: Then we must have $2a-1<0$ to ensure convergence.

Comment: Are you sure you typed the integral correctly? because $$ \frac{e^{a(2a-1)}}{1-2a} \neq e^{a^2}\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2} $$

Comment: Exactly.
I did type it right.
Is this question solvable using beta functions?

Comment: The answer you suggest fits with $\int_a^{+\infty}e^{2ax-x^2}\,dx$. Perhaps there is a misprint?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**. One has
$$
\int e^{cx}dx=\frac{e^{cx}}{c},\qquad c\ne0.
$$

Comment: But, how do I bring Beta functions is play, because simple integration won't work.

Comment: @Hari There is no need for the Beta function here...

Comment: @Hari why won't simple integration work?

Comment: @Dando18 I got what you two are saying, simple integration, with that condition is right. But I am trying to solve this question using Beta functions.

Answer (score 0):

Integrate using $\int e^{ax}dx = \frac{1}{a}e^{ax}+c$.

$$ \begin{align*} \int e^{(2a-1)x}dx &= \left[ \frac{e^{(2a-1)x}}{2a-1} \right]^\infty_{a} \\
&= \frac{e^{a(2a-1)}}{1-2a}, \quad \textrm{for } \Re[a]<1/2 . \\
\end{align*} $$

Where we require $a$ be less than $1/2$ so that the integrand converges at $\infty$ and the denominator is not $0$.